# deleting relationships in ndb entities (Google App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am implementing a Google App Engine based Web Application.
The app uses ndb and there are two entities (say A and B) with a one to many relationship implemented via this property in the A class model

```
 bObjects = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True);
```

I have an instance of A (a1) in relationship with three instance of B (b1,b2,b3)
I am trying to delete b2.
To this end I am trying to remove it from the relationship with a1 in this way

```
  a1.bObjects.remove(b2.key)
```

the command is executed but the element is not removed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to be clear since you don't show it in your example. Are you doing `a1.put()` after `a1.bObjects.remove(b2.key)`?

Comment: great! I always have to put it! thank you!

Comment: awesome, I'll make it an answer then.

Comment: the fact I was actually getting a1 from b2 like b2.aObject.get().bObjects.remove(b2.key) and I was not realizing I also had to do b2.aObject.get().put()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in the comments above you always need to call `put()` method to save and send the changes back to the Datastore.

In your example the proper code to save the changes would be:

```
  a1.bObjects.remove(b2.key)
  a1.put()
```